# Views Grouping by Field

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm looking to display a list of staff grouped by department.  I've figured out how to do this just fine with one exception.

I have a few staff who's time is split between 2 departments.  However, when I edit their department field and enter more than one department, they show up in a new section.  For example.

> Outreach
>
> > Joe Smith
> >
> > jane Smith
>
> Technical Services
>
> > Joe Johnson
>
> Outreach, Technical Services
>
> > Jane Johnson

Instead of having this separate display, I want Jane Johnson to be listed twice, under both Outreach and Technical Services.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you assigning the departments to the users? Through taxonomy, or a user field, or some other way?

Comment: Can you add a screenprint about how you defined your view (the screen you get when you "edit" the view? That might help to provide an accurate answer / suggestion (apart from the question reformatting I just applied, I hope).

Comment: @longboardnode raises a good point. If you add the department as a multi value taxonomy field and bring in the relationship in views you might pull this off. Taxonomy has the benefit of allowing you to add departments later on, whereas if it is a list of text then you are stuck should departments be added or removed later on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've had this answered yet, but in Drupal 7 and the latest version of Views, this is possible by doing the following:

Under Fields, click the one you want to configure, in your case it probably looks something like:
Content: Departments

Select Multiple Field Settings and it will drop-down to where you see a check mark in the box labelled:
Display all values in the same row

Uncheck this box and it should list your members twice, once in each department they are specified under.